# Flutter: Rotate and translate an image on a canvas

Tags: flutter, canvas

I am sure, it's quite simple, but I don't come behind it.

I have a canvas, let's say 400 x 200. Then I have an image with size 50 x 50.

I want to rotate the image by 30 degrees and then paint this rotated image to the original canvas. The original canvas coordinates for the (rotated) image center should be (100, 100).

My code:

```
 var imageSize = 50;

 canvas
    ..save()
    ..translate(imageSize / 2, imageSize / 2)
    ..rotate(30 * pi / 180.0)
    ..translate(-imageSize / 2, -imageSize / 2);

  paintImage(
      canvas: canvas,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      rect: Rect.fromCenter(
          center: Offset(50, 50), width: imageSize, height: imageSize 
      ),
      image: image);

  canvas.restore();
```

The rotation is done perfectly. But in the end the painted image is not on the position I expected. I guess because the positioning takes place on the still rotated canvas, not on the original one.

How can I place the image to the position I expect?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I managed it this way:

- translate before rotate, not other way round
- using `save()` and `restore()` twice

Don't know if it's the common way:

```
  var imageSize = 50;

  var translateX = 50 - imageSize / 2;
  var translateY = 50 - imageSize / 2;

  canvas
    ..save()
    ..translate(translateX, translateY);

  canvas
    ..save()
    ..translate(imageSize / 2, imageSize / 2)
    ..rotate(30 * pi / 180.0)
    ..translate(-imageSize / 2, -imageSize / 2);

  paintImage(
      canvas: canvas,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      rect: Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset(imageSize / 2, imageSize / 2), 
        width: imageSize, 
        height: imageSize 
      ),
      image: image);

  canvas.restore();
  canvas.restore();
```